# Why can't I initialize a static variable by calling a static function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

It is my understanding that as of Xcode 6.3 / Swift 1.2, I can use static variables and methods inside of a class.  However, the compiler doesn't like it when I try to initialize a static variable by calling a static function (I get the error 'Use of unresolved identifier getDefaultString' in the example below).  Here is a snippet that demonstrates my problem:

```
import Foundation

public class Settings {
    private static var _bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    static func getDefaultString(key: String) -> String {
        return _bundle.objectForInfoDictionaryKey(key) as! String
    }

    private static var _server = getDefaultString("DefaultServer")
    public class var server: String {
        get { return _server }
        set { _server = newValue }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me understand why I can't do this?

Comment: Does it work if you use `private static var _server = Settings.getDefaultString("DefaultServer")`?

Comment: As a matter of fact, it does.  But I don't understand why?

Answer (score 13):

This should work:

```
private static var _server = Settings.getDefaultString("DefaultServer")
```

I do not know exactly why, it seems that there is some sort of an assumption in the play that a method without type qualified in front of it is an instance method.  But that does not fully work as well.  E.g. this produces interesting result in playground:

```
    class Foo {

        static func initFoo() -> String {
            return "static"
        }

        func initFoo() -> String {
            return "instance"
        }

        static var foo: String = initFoo()

    }

    Foo.foo
```

... no need to qualify type in front of initFoo(), but still the static one is picked up.  A minor bug probably.

Answer (score 1):

You are forcing an unwrap of a possible (and actual) `nil` object.

```
return _bundle.objectForInfoDictionaryKey(key) as! String
```

`NSBundle`'s `objectForInfoDictionaryKey` can return nil –
its declaration:

```
func objectForInfoDictionaryKey(key: String) -> AnyObject?
```

my edit, as a playground:

```
import Foundation

class Settings {
    private static var _bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    static func getDefaultString(key: String) -> String? {
        return _bundle.objectForInfoDictionaryKey(key) as? String
    }

    private static var _server = Settings.getDefaultString("DefaultServer")

    class var server: String? {
        get { return _server }
        set { _server = newValue }
    }
}

Settings.server
```

You can, of course, fallback from a `nil` in some other fashion if you prefer.